# WoW runs faster on GNOME Shell compared to Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, games

I have been trying to run WoW on Ubuntu 12.04. When I run it on unity, the frame rate is very low and it is impossible to play. Although, when I launch it on gnome shell, for some reason, the frame rate gets very high and the playing experience is very comfortable. 
The problem is that I prefer running Unity instead of gnome shell, but I like to play WoW too. Is there a way to run WoW on Unity, with no lag?

Comment: @UriHerrera You might want to post that as an answer. (GNOME Shell uses 3D acceleration too, but it uses different compositing window manager, so this could still be the cause of the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to disable Compiz *before* you play games, it eats up quite a few FPS this however will leave you with no Unity at all, so if you wish to play games use Unity 2D instead.

Comment: I have been running wow on unity 2d and the game has a lot of rendering problems. Compiz is not being ran.